# App version ↔ Mac OS X version/build compatibility

Tags: macos, compatibility

I have a common question. There is some app. I know it's compatible with Mac OS X Version 10.7.5 (Build 11G63). May I be sure if it's fully compatible with:

- 10.7.5 (Build 11G63b)
- 10.7.4 (Build 11E53)
- 10.7.0
- 10.6.8
- 10.8.1
- ...

etc. I suppose the answer is always "no", because every build has its special features, it needs special testing. Is it really so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is always no (one cannot assume compatibility backwards or ahead). Universal truth that applies to everything running on anything.